# how to get values of array out

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I have this array

```
$pv->orderRecordsArray = array();


foreach($order->records as $i=>$orderRecord){

$pv->orderRecordsArray[] = $orderRecord->orderRecordID;  
        }

// print_r($pv->orderRecordsArray) for example
// shows Array ( [0] => 46839 [1] => 46840 [2] => 46841 )
```

I need to use the array values from above in my sql statement below.

```
$sql = "
    SELECT 
    *               
         FROM 
    table1               
    WHERE 
    orderRecordID IN (46741, 46742) 
         ";
```

so infront of IN I want $pv->orderRecordsArray results.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`implode`](http://php.net/implode) to generate such a list:

```
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM table1
        WHERE orderRecordID IN (" . implode(', ', $pv->orderRecordsArray) . ")";
```

But you should also consider a [subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html) or [Join of your tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

Comment: Don't forget about sanitation!  (Probably with `array_map`.)

Comment: @strager: I think the values are also coming from a database query.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = 'SELECT *
        FROM table1               
        WHERE orderRecordID IN ('.implode(',',$pv->orderRecordsArray).')';
```

Comment: Don't forget about sanitation!  (Probably with `array_map`.)

Comment: It depends to how he launches this query ^^